# how to customize vAxis gridlines become dash with google API

Tags: css, google-api, google-visualization

I'm trying to customize vAxis gridlines become dash. But, it didn't run very well, everytime I change stroke-dasharray value in css it still blur.

please, is someone know how to change vAxis gridline into dash?

```js
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);

      var options = {
   width:'100%',
   focusTarget: 'category',
   backgroundColor: 'transparent',
   chartArea: {
    left: 20,
    top: 10,
    width: '100%',
    height: '70%'
   },
   bar: {
    groupWidth: '70%'
   },
   hAxis: {
    textStyle: {
     fontSize: 9,
     color:'#929496'
    }
   },
   vAxis: {
    baselineColor: '#e6e6e6',
    gridlines: {
     color: '#e6e6e6',
     count: 9
    },
    textStyle: {
     fontSize: 9,
     color:'#929496'
    }
   },
   legend: {
    position: 'bottom',
    textStyle: {
     fontSize: 9,
     color:'#929496'
    }
   },
   animation: {
    duration: 300,
    easing: 'out',
    startup: true
   }
  };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```css
#chart_div svg > g:nth-child(3) > g:nth-child(2) > g:first-child rect{ 
 fill: none;
 stroke-width: 1;
 stroke: #ddd;
 stroke-dasharray: 5 5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: there are no standard options for this -- you'll probably have to replace the `<rect>` elements with `<line>` elements to sharpen the appearance -- and if you're planning to use the method `getImageURI`, these changes will not show thru...

Comment: @mDesto : were you able to get dashed lines for gridlines.

Comment: @jitenshah I'm afraid not